# Tensorflow - how to augment images and bounding boxes during training with tfrecord files

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, data-augmentation

I currently have a training pipeline using images and labels in a tfrecord format. Augmenting them using tf.image has been super easy but I am limited to augmentations that don't effect that location of the objects because the tf.image functions don't seem to effect the bounding boxes.

Currently I have this:

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
    lambda image, label: (tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32), label)
).map(
    lambda image, label: (tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=0.0, upper=1.0), label)
).repeat().shuffle(buffer_size=512)
```

But I would really love to add some random flipping, rotating, skewing, and cropping to make it robust. 
The `tf.image.random_flip` functions would be ideal but I dont know how to deal with flipping the bounding boxes as well.

I was looking into using the `imgaug` package, but I don't know how to handle the tfrecord bounding box data, or if it would be efficient to do during training because it uses numpy.

Is there a simpler way of augmenting the data during training? Or is there even a simple way of using `imgaug` with tfrecords so that I could do all the augmentation before training and save them as new images?

Comment: Try albumentations package

Comment: @SajanGohil The package looks very useful, but I don't see anything about tfrecord support? My problem is that I don't know how to get the bbox data from the tfrecord files to use these packages like you would with a standard image format.